# How can i separate a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

i have a problem. I need to separate a tuple in 2 arguments, like this (0, 1)

I try this and it works, but i don't like how it looks. What other method can I use?

```
numbers = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

print(numbers[0:2], numbers[2:4], numbers[4:6], numbers[6:8])

(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
list(zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2]))
```

Ouput:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[numbers[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, len(numbers) - 1, 2)]
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
numbers = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2):
    print(numbers[i:i+2])
```

in case you are wondering 3rd argument of range specifies step which means it will loop through that range by 2 values like this: 0, 2, 4, 6 and so on

Answer (score 0):

your question is really unclear but to achieve

```
numbers = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
print(numbers[0:2], numbers[2:4], numbers[4:6], numbers[6:8])
```

but in a flexible python code you can to it like this

```
numbers = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
for i in range(len(numbers)):  
    if i.__index__() % 2:
        continue
    try:
        print(numbers[i], numbers[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        print(numbers[i])
```